# Breaking For loop with Handler()

Tags: android, for-loop, handler

How can I break the `for() loop` when 1 validation has return true.

```
public void printOut (){
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   for (final int[] x = {0}; x[0] < Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem.toString()); x[0]++) {
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

               //printer for my device
               int query = PrinterInterface.queryStatus();
               if (query == 1){
                   // return true
                   //printing goes here..
               }else{
                   // returns false
                   x[0] = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem.toString());
               }
           }
       },2000 * x[0]);
   }
```

}

This is my code ATM, If the `query` value returns not equal to 1, It will go on the else statement and making the variable `x[0]` to be equal on the `Spinner`. But the problem is it is still looping. How can I make it stop? Thanks!

*UPDATE*

I find the problem. its on `}, 2000 * loopVariable[0]);` how can I interrupt this part?. or stop the `Handler()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it!. The solution is just one line codes -_- and I also add an variable for `Runnable`. Thank you for helping especially pskink.

```
public void printOut (){
final Handler handler = new Handler();
for (final int[] x = {0}; x[0] < Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem.toString()); x[0]++) {
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           //printer for my device
           int query = PrinterInterface.queryStatus();
           if (query == 1){
               // return true
               //printing goes here..
           }else{
               // returns false
               x[0] = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem.toString());
               handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
           }
       }
   },2000 * x[0]);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to make var for handle `canceled` status

For example, by your code.

```
     public void printOut (){
           final Handler handler = new Handler();
           boolean isCanceled = false
           for (final int[] x = {0}; (x[0] < Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem.toString()) && !isCanceled); x[0]++) {
                 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {

                             //printer for my device
                             int query = PrinterInterface.queryStatus();
                             if (query == 1){
                                   isCanceled = true
                                   // return true
                                   //printing goes here..
                             }else{
                                   // returns false
                                   x[0] = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem.toString());
                             }
                         }
                },2000 * x[0]);
     }
```

And, if you want to handle result, you need to add callback.

But, I don't understand, why you use `poseDelayed`, in `for` you are start all handlers.

Better, If you check `query`, after that execute logic into `Handler`

Comment: still not working. it still looping based what I've inputted

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you using `handler` inside `for`, if your printing code required background processing and update the UI try using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), it have `doInBackground`, `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` so you can handle your code more efficient.